# Error on updating Wordpress 4.7.2 to 4.8

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to update my Wordpress version from 4.7.2 to 4.8. When I try to do it, i do not get any error message, instead I get the following message which doesn't make much sense. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Message:

Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.8-no-content.zip…

ys) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString()); document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value; }; $( document ).on( 'click.vc-notice-dismiss', '.vc-notice-dismiss', function ( e ) { e.preventDefault(); var $el = $( this ).closest( '#vc_license-activation-notice' ); $el.fadeTo( 100, 0, function () { $el.slideUp( 100, function () { $el.remove(); } ); } ); setCookie( 'vchideactivationmsg_vc11', '4.11.2.1', 30 ); } ); })( window.jQuery );

Comment: It seems to have something to do with [Visual Composer](https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/visual-composer/), I would try to disable this plugin before updating.

Comment: @Cyclonecode you were right! Thanks!